# Installation issue (drush problem?)

Tags: aegir

I was trying to install Aegir following the [Automatic install guide](http://community.aegirproject.org/node/400), but I get an error. I've tried to install Aegir 2, then tried also Aegir 3, but the error is the same. Any clues?

Here's the message:

> The following settings will be used:
>     Aegir frontend URL: site.dev.local
>     Master server FQDN: site.dev.local
>     Aegir root: /var/aegir
>     Aegir user: aegir
>     Web group: www-data
>     Web server: apache
>     Web server port: 80
>     Aegir DB host: localhost
>     Aegir DB user: root
>     Aegir DB password: 
>     Aegir DB port: 3306
>     Aegir version: 7.x-3.x
>     Aegir platform path: /var/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.x
>     Admin email: aegir@site.dev.local
>
> Aegir install profile: hostmaster
>
> Do you really want to proceed with the install (y/n): y
>   Enabling hosting-queued daemon
>
> The drush command '@hostmaster pm-enable hosting_queued' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.                       [error]
>   A Drupal installation directory could not be found                                                                                                                                                     [error]
>
> dpkg: error processing package aegir3-hostmaster (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aegir3:
>    aegir3 depends on aegir3-hostmaster (>= 3.0.1); however:
>     Package aegir3-hostmaster is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package aegir3 (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                                                                                                             Errors were encountered while processing:
>    aegir3-hostmaster
>    aegir3
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common problem that could cause this is a broken mail setup.

Please the if you can sent an email from the server's cli to aegir@site.dev.local

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today, here's how I solved it:

**Set `-x` in the script which is failing.**

You can do this by editing the `.postinst` script, eg `/var/lib/dpkg/info/aegir3-hostmaster.postinst` in my situation. Replace `#! /bin/sh` with `#! /bin/sh -x` at the top of the script; when executed, the postinst script will then print out each line as it's executed.

**Set `DPKG_DEBUG=developer`.**

```
export DPKG_DEBUG=developer
```

This will activate debug output in various script commands.

**Re-run the installation.**

For me, this was `dpkg --configure --pending` as I'd already attempted to install the package and it had failed during configuration.

**Read the output.**

Seems obvious, but the first couple times I didn't read back far enough, and there *was* a useful error message further up.

In my case (quite possibly not yours, dear reader), the issue was that the permissions of `/var/aegir/platforms` in my Vagrant environment did not permit the aegir user to create the directory to install its hostmaster install. Thus no `@hostmaster` alias, no way to enable `hosting_queued`, and an error message which didn't clearly point to a resolvable situation.

**Fix the root problem.**

This will vary, as the error in this question is associated with many different causes documented across the internet, including:

- MySQL validate password plugin not accepting the generated password. (Generate a better password, or reconfigure / disable that plugin.)
- The aegir hostname not being resolvable, so the site being inaccessible. (Add the aegir hostname in `/etc/hosts`)
- Filesystem permissions preventing installation. (Make sure aegir owns the platforms directory.)

HTH